# VBA Button Calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of numbers in cells d4:p5 and want to be able to multiply all by 1.36 (and back again) with the results appearing in the same cells using a button click.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is entirely possible using VBA. Perhaps you might want to rephrase or specify the qeustion.

Comment: How can I do this please?

Comment: Do you have any code you've tryed (you should attach it to your question then)? Or you're starting new project? It is easier to modify/fix your code, not to mention it is more useful for other SO askers as it provides educational value and shows SO answerers your research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Start a project:

[image: StartingProject]
Add WordArt object, Picture, Figure or Button (basicaly anything you can attach your macro to)
[image: AddingButton]
Go to Visual Basic Editor (hotkey is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)
and insert a new module in your vba project.
[image]
Enter the following code to your new module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Multiply()
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As Range
    '   This is your working sheet, modify "Sheet1" to the actual name
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    '   This is your range, modify "D4:P5" to your actual range address
    Set MyRange = MySheet.Range("D4:P5")
    '   Condition on "A1" value, if it is true, multiply, otherwise divide by 1.36
    '   You can change "A1" to any unnecessary cell address
    If MySheet.Range("A1") Then
        '   Evaluate "evaluates" formulas you input in them
        '   This formula looks like "=$D$4:$P$5 * 1.36"
        MyRange.Value = Evaluate("=" & MyRange.Address & "*1.36")
    Else
        MyRange.Value = Evaluate("=" & MyRange.Address & "/1.36")
    End If
    '   Change "A1" value to an opposite
    MySheet.Range("A1").Value = Not MySheet.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Attach "Multiply" macro to your button

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MultiplyCells()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, rowLength As Integer, columnLength As 
 Integer, rowStart As Integer, columnStart As Integer
 Dim multiplier As Double

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourSheet")

 rowLength = 5 'in your example. To make it dynamically use rows.count
 rowStart = 4

 columnLength = 16 'in your example. To make it dynamically use column.count
 columnStart = 4

 multiplier = 1.36

 For x = rowStart To rowLength Step 1
     For y = columnStart To columnLength Step 1
         ws.Cells(x, y).Value = ws.Cells(x, y).Value * multiplier
     Next y
 Next x
End Sub
```

Then create a button by using developer tools  -> insert -> button.
Right click on the button you just created and assign the Sub MultiplyCells to it.

Now you should be able to create a second button and apply the above logic "backwards".